# Is there a function on google sheets that can show where the information from a particular cell is on another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am working with two sheets on drive and I would like to know if there is a possibility to make some sort of confirmation if the information from another sheet is on the other sheet o not and, if we can show it where this cell is. With the link bellow, I think it will be easier to understand.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sYFz5zJic3HMMh4F1QBg7N1-lm6frNCgSWFxqaC0d54/edit?usp=sharing

I made some comments trying to explain it a bit better.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). The sample spreadsheet gives _"Options to download print and copy have been disabled on this file"_ which makes it hard to develop a solution. Please modify the sharing settings so that the spreadsheet can be edited or at least copied. Also show the desired result for the first three companies.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, I have allowed anyone with the link to edit the sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sYFz5zJic3HMMh4F1QBg7N1-lm6frNCgSWFxqaC0d54/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: While a like to a spreadsheet might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. Considering this, the question should describe the relevant parts of the spreadsheet as well some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to fill the state into every company row:

`=arrayformula( if( len(C4:C); A2; iferror(1/0) ) )`

...and this to look up those states per company:

`=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(A2:A; { 'COMPANY STATE'!C4:D; 'COMPANY STATE'!G4:H }; 2; false) ) )`

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sYFz5zJic3HMMh4F1QBg7N1-lm6frNCgSWFxqaC0d54/edit#gid=2105898933).